# Reading data in NIO

Tags: java, nio

I'm trying to write my own NIO server with my custom protocol. As always I put the number of bytes before the actual bytes. Like this:

```
                   509234
Number of bytes----^|||||----Actual bytes
```

The problem is when I extracted `SelectionKey` and got the `SocketChannel` like this:

```
SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(128);
int numRead = channel.read(buffer); // <---- 4, not 5
```

I can potentially receive the number of bytes: `5` and the actual bytes `0923`, where the last byte `4` is not yet available to read from the channel. But for processing I need ***all*** bytes.

How to deal with such a situation? Do I need to store the `SocketChannel` somewhere (e.g. `Map<SocketChannel, byte[]>`) to keep track of it? And when the rest of data is available to read from the channel I will add the data to the `Map`

Comment: SocketChannel will only read as many bytes as are available. Typically, one has to put the `read` in some sort of loop, e.g. see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451118/java-nio-socketchannel-read-method-all-time-return-0-why

Comment: @cello Are you sure it's a good idea to waste CPU resources for waiting for data? Looks like classic blocking IO...

Comment: @cello Maybe I dont understand what you meant... Couldn't you clarify a bit please?

Comment: no, but in the linked question there are multiple answers that already take care of that argument

Comment: @cello Not exactly... I understand that we need event loop to query the `Selector`. But from extracted selection keys we can only read the data that is available. How about implementing a custom protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `ByteBuffer` per channel. When it's readable, read into it, and when you have a complete message in there, process it.

You can associate the buffer with the channel via a `Map`, but it's simpler to use the key attachment facility.

Comment: You mean put `ByteBuffer` attachement inside a key?

Comment: But what if `ByteBuffer.size` is not enough to store all message? Do I have to resize it each time?

Comment: *Make* it big enough. Make it as big as the biggest possible message.